# Can we rotate about a plane or other multi-dimensional "axis"?

Tags: geometry, rotations

I was examining the nature of rotating objects and realized a pattern that could be extended to higher dimensions. If you have a line (1 dimensional) and rotate it along a point on the line (1 dimensional), the line rotates into the 2nd dimension. Similarly, if you have a square (2 dimensional) and rotate it along a line on the square, it rotates into the 3rd dimension.

> My question is whether or not the trend would continue to where, if you rotate a cube (3 dimensional) about the plane of a square, it would rotate into the 4th dimension. Rather, are axes greater than one dimension possible?

Comment: "rotate a cube on a square" ??? "turning the object inside out" ???

Comment: @Yves Daoust. Yes, I believe that is what would happen if you rotate an object through the 4th dimension. That is unimportant though, and I probably should have left that out. The question is whether or not two dimensional axes work.

Comment: My question marks mean that I can't understand what you say.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely follow you here, but you are right that axes of rotation aren't one-dimensional as you go to higher dimensions; they have co-dimension two. That is, in $n$-dimensions, a rotation is about an $(n - 2)$-dimensional affine subspace. This is a point in $2$ dimensions, a line in $3$, and a plane in $4$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust. Ah, I see. Well, one definition of rotation is motion where all the points of the object are the same distance from an axis. If you rotate a square on a point, all points of the square will always be the same distance from that point that they were, and if you rotate your perspective of it, it will appear to be the same. I think this same idea may apply to higher dimensions. A cube rotated along a square would need to keep all points of the cube the same distance away from the square, yet still rotate in a mind-boggling way. I'm not sure how to better describe it.

Comment: @user757704 That is fascinating. Do you know of any sources where I can learn more about that?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't particularly. This is stuff I picked up when learning about inner product spaces. I should also point out, what we're talking about are called [simple rotations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotations_in_4-dimensional_Euclidean_space), whereas more complicated rotations are formed by composing simple rotations (in finite dimensions, at least).

Comment: @user757704 That is okay. Thank you for the new information. I shall do some research here.

Comment: This can be done, and is. And in four dimensions that axis of rotation of a sphere can be a single point, just as in two dimensions. Not so in three. $\qquad$

Comment: Do you know of any simulation or paper that describes what this would look like? Also, I did not know that you could rotate among a point in 4 dimensions. That trend is fascinating.

Answer (score 0):

In four-dimensional space, objects do indeed rotate around a plane.  In fact, they can rotate around two planes at the same time.  When you model rotations using quaternions, you essentially get two rotations around two separate planes; however, rotation is performed using a conjugation operation, and you can view the second product as undoing the unwanted rotation and doubling up the desired rotation.  (That's not a particularly insightful way of thinking about it, but it's basically right, I think.)

Comment: That is fascinating! Could you theoretically rotate a cube about a square and bring it into four-dimensional space? Or is that not how that functions?

Answer (score 0):

A rotation (in according orientation) is being described by the following matrix
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}cos(\phi)&sin(\phi)&0&\cdots&0\\
-sin(\phi)&cos(\phi)&0&\cdots&0\\
0&0&1&0&\vdots\\
\vdots&\vdots&0&\ddots&0\\
0&0&\cdots&0&1\end{array}\right)$$
i.e. it is the identity within a subspace of codimension 2 (searving as "axis"), while the rotation moves (everything else) along a 2-dimensional path around it.

--- rk